# $X \cap (Y \setminus Z) = (X \cap Y) \setminus (X \cap Z)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

As the title suggests, what is the easiest way to see that$$X \cap (Y \setminus Z) = (X \cap Y) \setminus (X \cap Z)?$$

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Math.SE! What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

$$(X \cap Y) \setminus (X \cap Z) = (X \cap Y) \cap (X \cap Z)^C = (X \cap Y) \cap (X^C \cup Z^C) \\  = (X \cap Y \cap X^C) \cup (X \cap Y \cap Z^C)  = X \cap(Y \cap Z^C) = X \cap (Y \setminus Z) $$

Answer (score 0):

If $\alpha \in X \cap (Y \setminus Z)$ then $\alpha \in X$ and $\alpha \in (Y \setminus Z) \implies \alpha \in Y, ~ \alpha \not\in Z$. So $\alpha \in (X \cap Y).$ But $\alpha \not \in Z$ so $\alpha \not \in X \cap Z$. Therefore $\alpha \in (X \cap Y) \setminus (X \cap Z).$ Now if $\alpha \in (X \cap Y) \setminus (X \cap Z)$ then $\alpha \in X$ and $\alpha \in Y$ but $\alpha \not \in X \cap Z$ so $\alpha \not \in Z$. Thus $\alpha \in X \cap (Y \setminus Z)$.